# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Mageworx_Customoptions_Helper_Data' not found

Tags: product, module, custom-options, custom, backend

I cannot find where Mageworx dir is...

```
/app/code/local
/app/code/core/
```

I didn't install the extension but seems to be called it in my page.. and send an error in the admin page.. in the product details, custom options.

need a help. Thanks

Comment: try to search customoptions in your custom modules

Comment: where i can find the dir?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on a *nix based system you can call a program called "locate" to find folders across your system.

In my case Mageworx is located in **includes/src/MageWorx***
You could also check if the MageWorx/Customoptions module is activated via the admin panel.

Comment: there are no mageworks module in the configuration page in admin page also..

Comment: Seems like the template you installed is dependent on a module.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the error message the mageworx customoptions helper class was called somewhere in your code. 
You can try to search `helper('customoptions')` or `helper('mageworx_customoptions')` in a whole project and remove it, or you can add a condition to check "is a module installed?" before you are trying to call it's helper class.